# convert PDF file to byte array in android

Tags: java, android, file, pdf

i want convert PDF file to byte array in (onActivityResult)
I tried several different ways but it didn't work
Please answer if anyone knows.

Update :

```
  case 1212 :
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                        Uri uri = data.getData();
                        File file = new File(uri.getPath());
                        int size = (int) file.length();
                        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
                        try {
                            BufferedInputStream buf = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
                            buf.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                            buf.close();
                        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"FileNotFound",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"IOException",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }else Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"خطا!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

this code show FileNotFound Toast

Comment: why would  you want to do that? what if your pdf is 10 or 100 MB long?

Comment: `uri.getPath()` won't return you the file path usually. Use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver#openInputStream(android.net.Uri) to open stream from Uri, and then read it into byte array.

Comment: `but it didn't work` how exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Package java.nio.file from java 7

```
Path pdfFilePath = Paths.get("/file/path/your_file.pdf"); //File path
byte[] pdfByteArray = Files.readAllBytes(pdfFilePath );
```